# Clean AND "dirty" url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I made a htaccess for clean urls that is processed by PHP after, however for my search option I want a youtube-like '?q=searchquery'.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?d=$1 [L]
```

That's my htaccess and it works for all urls but 'http://www.website.com/search/?q=searchquery' doesn't. Now I've tried other rewrites such as these

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/\?(.*)/$ index.php?d=$1&$2

RewriteRule ^(.*)/\?q=(.*)/$ index.php?d=$1&q=$2
```

They dont work.

I also had a look the entire URI using the [R] flag and everything from the question mark doesn't show.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?d=$1 [L]
```

Using the url: http://www.website.com/search/?q=searchquery displays: http://www.website.com/search/

Edit:
So how do I do both? \o/

Comment: What's a clean URL and a dirty URL?

Comment: Clean url: http://www.website.com/product/product-name/
Dirty url: http://www.website.com/products.php?p=product-name

Does the same thing

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `QSA` (Query String Append) flag:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?d=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If the URL is called with a query string, the query string is appended to the generated URL.

PS: You can't match a query string within the rewrite rule. The query string is stripped off, before the rules are matched.

Comment: @Tim: If that's the answer you were looking for, click on the transparent green tick next to it ;)

Comment: I've tried that about a million times, but it tells me I have to wait. I'll definately keep clicking until it works! Thanks man

Comment: @Tim: Probably there is some timespan which you can't accept the answer in.

Comment: Yeh I did it, made an account and gave you thumb up, even though its an arrow \o/